# Filesystem bundle deployment in Glassfish v3

Tags: deployment, glassfish, osgi

I'm trying to use the filesystem way (just drop the bundle) to deploy an OSGi bundle in Glassfish v3. When I put the bundle in autodeploy/bundles/, it doesn't work, no logs, nada, zip.

- When I try the admin console or the telnet way, both works...
- When I put the JAR in autodeploy, the logs tells me it cannot handle the file format

I've enabled the Apache Felix File Install (3.1.10) (it shows as started in the OSGi Felix console). I've checked the org.apache.felix.fileinstall-autodeploy-bundles.cfg file and the property felix.fileinstall.dir: it read as ${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/autodeploy/bundles/ (default config).

I'm basically stuck and would be grateful for help from Glassfish/OSGi experts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a misonfiguration on my part :-/

For additional information, follow this procedure: http://markmail.org/message/itphcq7rqdc76gys

Answer (score 0):

Which version of GlassFish are you using? You can run "asadmin version" to find out the version. Can you run "jstack " and see if there is any threads with name fileinstall in it?

Sahoo

Comment: this would probably make a better comment than answer

Comment: Hi Sahoo,

First of all, thanks for your answer.

 - asadmin version gives me "GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1 (build 43)"
 - I used jstack and found no fileinstall thread

I'm available for further info.